# Unsing integer Variable to process linux cut command fields

Tags: linux, cut

The following command below does not succeed.

```
for i in {1..5} ; do cat /etc/fstab | egrep "(ext3|ext4|xfs)" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"/" -f1-$i ; done
```

It seems that **$i** is ignored completely. It always returns instead result of

```
cut -d"/" -f1-
```

Any idea why it fails?

Thanks in advance!

The command itself is a part of a script that should help me to auto re-arrange fstab lines to match the right mount order (like /test/subfolder must come after /test was mounted and not before).

Comment: Why are you doing this with `cut`? `awk` has a built-in `split()` function.

Comment: `awk` also has built-in regexp matching, so you don't need `egrep`.

Comment: I tried your code, the `$i` substitution worked fine. I think the problem is that if a pathname only has 1 field, it will still be printed when you do `-f1-2` and `-f1-3`. So all the short pathnames get printed multiple times.

Comment: make sure you are running the script in bash interpreter and not "sh" (#!/bin/sh). I copied your code and runs fine in Ubuntu 15.10, bash 4.3.42(1)

Comment: BTW, when you have a line like `/test/subfolder`, field 1 is the empty field before the first `/`. So `-f1-1` prints nothing.

Comment: thanks a lot. not sure why it did not work before. in fact now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it didn't work for `zsh` shell. BUT I tried it in `bash` and it does work, so if you are using `zsh` just run the command with `bash` and it should work ;)

Comment: If he were using a shell that doesn't understand `{1..5}` syntax he would get an error message from `cut`, it wouldn't act like `-f1-`.

Comment: I was saying that for me it acted like `-f1-` just like he said (so it didn't work). But in bash it does.

Comment: I find that very surprising. If it doesn't expand the `{1..5}` syntax, it should produce `cut -f1-{1..5}`, which is an invalid argument to `cut`.